# Что значит "!" в конструкции сo spread оператором?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Нашел в коде который писали до меня такое выражение:

```
[...set!].map (() => {do smth})
```

Тип переменной set - Set.
Код написан на TypeScript

Вопрос заключается в том, что значит в этой конструкции "!" после получения элементов set?

Comment: как я понимаю проверка что объект не null и не undefined  https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-exclamation-mark-typescript/#:~:text=marks%20in%20TypeScript-,What%20is%20the%20TypeScript%20exclamation%20mark%3F,possibility%20of%20it%20being%20undefined.    ..........   https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/exclamation-mark-in-ts.aspx

Comment: Не проверка, а утверждение, что данная переменная не null и не undefined. Мы говорим компилятору, что в данном месте кода пусть не придумывает и не парится, а доверится нам (как оно будет на самом деле, не его собачье дело) :)

Comment: @AlexanderChernin вообще походит на костылища)) Объявлять переменные как nullable и применять `!` для отмены :D

Comment: Если использовать этот оператор бездумно и пихать везде где попало, то смысл его теряется. Он нужен в малых дозах и разумно ) Например, вы создали переменную типа как в примере, и везде и всюду используете ее как обычно со всеми проверками и предупреждениями, но, в особых местах вы уверены, что переменная никогда не станет null, или undefined, - просто уверены, и вам надо, чтобы код работал и компилировался без всяких проверок. Бывают такие случаи, не часто, но бывают.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за пояснения! Теперь все встало на свои места)

Comment: @АлексейШимаинский Предлагаю оформить ваш комментарий в виде ответа

Comment: Лучше давайте закроем вопрос как дубликат существующего вопроса